# Wrong grand total when using Calculated Field

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a simple pivot table, but I'm using Calculated Field values.

The raw data used for the pivot table is like a transaction log, as shown below:

| DATE | STOCK | QTY | PRICE | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/2023 | AAPL | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 03/2023 | AAPL | 2 | 120 | 240 |
| 03/2023 | GOOG | 2 | 60 | 120 |
| 03/2023 | GOOG | 3 | 80 | 240 |

The sheet also has the current price of a ticker with the `GOOGLEFINANCE(..)` function, as shown below:

| TICKER | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 158.28 |
| GOOG | 103.06 |

The pivot table groups the transactions by the ticker name, sums up the `TOTAL` per transaction `QTY * PRICE`, and shows the current value `QTY * 'CURRENT PRICE'`. The current price is a lookup to the current price table expressed as `=VLOOKUP(STOCK,$K$7:$L$10,2, FALSE)*SUM(QTY)` in the pivot table as a calculated field.

However, the Grand Total of the `CURR POSITION` column shows a wrong value. It shows `$3,044.75` instead of `$1,150.88`. It should sum the `VLOOKUP` value, but it shows a different value.

How can I fix this?

[**Sample sheet for better visualization here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F4O0WQoI4Dllj9-I7H841JAXHHJg_LyRLmUjtf6XZvU/edit#gid=2100307022)

And prints bellow:

[image: print of the pivot table]
[image: print of the CURR POSITION calculated field]

Comment: Totals would likely be better at the top or somewhere with easy access imo. For ex, if you have 100 stocks, how will you be able to quickly glance at overall performance? Scroll down 100 rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by using a `query()` formula instead of a pivot table, like this:

```
=let( 
  transactions, B6:E16, 
  tickers, offset(transactions, 0, 0, , 1), 
  quantity, offset(transactions, 0, 1, , 1), 
  position_, lambda(t, q, q * vlookup(t, K7:L10, columns(K7:L10), false)), 
  totals_, lambda(col, if(sum(col), to_dollars(sum(col)), "Grand Total")), 
  table, query( 
    { transactions, map(tickers, quantity, position_) }, 
    "select Col1, sum(Col4), sum(Col5) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label sum(Col4) 'Invested', sum(Col5) 'Current position' ", 
    1 
  ), 
  { table; bycol(table, totals_) } 
)
```

Another workaround would be to re-calculate the totals in the pivot table like this:

```
=let( 
  pivot, query( { G6:I13 }, "where Col1 is not null and Col1 <> 'Grand Total' ", 1), 
  totals_, lambda(col, if(sum(col), to_dollars(sum(col)), "Grand Total")), 
  { pivot; bycol(pivot, totals_) } 
)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [bycol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032) and the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F4O0WQoI4Dllj9-I7H841JAXHHJg_LyRLmUjtf6XZvU/edit#gid=2100307022).